# why mime part is coming '0' while importing email using Gmail API python?

Tags: python, api, gmail, mime-types

I am trying to get mime part of emails using Gmail API with Python but for some of email I am getting '0'(zero) as mime part. can you please explain why it is happening.

When I tried same email by forwarding to different account then code is working fine.(why mime part will change when we forward email, is there any way to get mime part as in forwarded email without forwarding it)

while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,q=query,pageToken=page_token).execute()
      messages.extend(response['messages'])
      print (response['messages'])
    for message in messages:
        print (message['id'])
        print (message['threadId'])
        msg_Id = message['id']

```
    print('----------New Message--------------')
    message1 = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_Id,format='raw').execute()

    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message1['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
    mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
    print ("From:",mime_msg['from'])
    print (mime_msg)

    if mime_msg.is_multipart():
        for part in mime_msg.walk():       
            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True) #to control automatic email-style MIME decoding (e.g., Base64, uuencode, quoted-printable)

                body = body.decode(encoding="utf-8")
                print(body)

                results = body.split(" ")
                print(results)
```